# How to get a particular script tag?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to build a download manager script with python, The web page contains some script tags, i want to isolate a particular script, the script  `html5player.setVideoUrlHigh('https://*****');`,

I don't know how to go about it, I was able to get all the script tags but i am unable to get the script tag with this code `html5player.setVideoUrlHigh('https://*****');`

Here is my python code

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
Url = '*****'
pg = urlopen(Url)
sp = BeautifulSoup(pg)
script_tag = sp.find_all('script')
# print(script_tag[1])
print(re.search("setVideoHLS\(\'(.*?)\'\)", script_tag).group(1))
```

The script tag i want to get is this:

```
<script>
    logged_user = false;
    var static_id_cdn = 17;
    var html5player = new HTML5Player('html5video', '56420147');
    if (html5player) {
        html5player.setVideoTitle('passionate hotel room');
        html5player.setSponsors(false);
        html5player.setVideoUrlLow('https://*****');
        html5player.setVideoUrlHigh('https://******');
        html5player.setVideoHLS('https://****');
        html5player.setThumbUrl('https://**');
        html5player.setStaticDomain('***');
        html5player.setHttps();
        html5player.setCanUseHttps();
        document.getElementById('html5video').style.minHeight = '';
        html5player.initPlayer();
   }
```

How can I get parameter from this function `html5player.setVideoUrlHigh('https://******').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the script  tag using this code,

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<script>    logged_user = false;
var static_id_cdn = 17;
var html5player = new HTML5Player('html5video', '56420147');
if (html5player) {
    html5player.setVideoTitle('passionate hotel room');
    html5player.setSponsors(false);
    html5player.setVideoUrlLow('https://*****');
    html5player.setVideoUrlHigh('https://******');
    html5player.setVideoHLS(''https://****');
    html5player.setThumbUrl('https://**');
    html5player.setStaticDomain('***');
    html5player.setHttps();
    html5player.setCanUseHttps();
    document.getElementById('html5video').style.minHeight = '';
    html5player.initPlayer();
}</script>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(HTML)

txt = soup.script.get_text()
print(txt)
```

Output:

```
logged_user = false;
var static_id_cdn = 17;
var html5player = new HTML5Player('html5video', '56420147');
if (html5player) {
    html5player.setVideoTitle('passionate hotel room');
    html5player.setSponsors(false);
    html5player.setVideoUrlLow('https://*****');
    html5player.setVideoUrlHigh('https://******');
    html5player.setVideoHLS(''https://****');
    html5player.setThumbUrl('https://**');
    html5player.setStaticDomain('***');
    html5player.setHttps();
    html5player.setCanUseHttps();
    document.getElementById('html5video').style.minHeight = '';
    html5player.initPlayer();
   }
```

## EDIT

```
import requests
import bs4
import re

url = 'url'
r = requests.get(url)
bs = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
scripts = bs.find_all('script')
src = scripts[7] #Needed script is in position 7
print(re.search("html5player.setVideoUrlHigh\(\'(.*?)\'\)", str(src)).group(1))
```

Comment: Thats not what i mean, The parameters do change in `html5player.setVideoUrlHigh()`, And the page is very dynamic, I mean how can i get the parameter inside this script function `html5player.setVideoUrlHigh()`, `The 'https://*****'`, how can i isolate that script tag and get the parameter

Comment: The page contains a lot of script tags, How can i get that particular script tag and the parameter in that function

Comment: If there have multiple script tags, then my function gets all the script tags as bs4.element.ResultSet it means is you can access them by x[0],x[1] so on. Also is there are multiple html5player.setVideoUrlHigh() stage it will return all the https*** parameters into list called values.  All you have to do is edit function as your desire.

Comment: i resolved the error message, but now it came with the parameter and it added `)` to it

Comment: you assume the script tag is at position 7, i want to be able to get it dynamically, because in another website, it wont be at position 7